# What is the average temperature of all planets at 1 bar?

Tags: planet, temperature

Jupiter's (and Saturn's) "surface" temperature is defined as that at 1 bar. It is inconsistent to say the other planet's surface is their hard surface. Applying the same measure what is the equivalent standard temperature of all the IAU defined planets?

Comment: Re *It is inconsistent to say the other planet's surface is their hard surface.* So be it. The  Sun is also a gaseous body, so it, like the giant planets, does not have a well defined surface. The Sun's "surface" is not defined in terms of pressure. It's defined in terms of whether light can escape.

Answer (score 1):

At 1 bar (0.9869 atm / 14.5 psi) pressure level the planets have the following average temperatures:

- Venus: 30 degrees Celsius (1 bar level is about 33 mi or 53 km high)
- The Earth: 15 deg C
- Jupiter: minus 145 deg C
- Saturn: minus 178 deg C
- Uranus: minus 197 deg C
- Neptune: minus 200 deg C
- Titan's temperature ranges from minus 180 deg Celsius on the surface to minus 93 deg Celsius in the upper stratosphere. Titan's surface air pressure is 1.45 atm (1.47 bar).

Mercury has no atmosphere while Mars' atmosphere doesn't reach 1 bar anywhere on the planet.

Comment: They will reach 1 bar under the surface.

Comment: @user2617804 Mars' atmosphere doesn't reach 1 bar anywhere on its surface nor in any caverns. As far as we know it doesn't even reach the Armstrong limit (0.0618 atm). Pressure on Mars is highest in the Hellas Basin at 0.012 atm.

Comment: For those who want to know : [The Armstrong Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_limit) on WIkipedia.

Comment: I've up voted but in Stack Exchange it's generally expected to support answers with sources. While these sound like reasonable numbers, it's impossible for future readers to tell if these are correct or just made-up random numbers. Can you add a short explanation of what sources you used and how you arrived at these values? *Thanks!*

Comment: somewhat related to the Mars discussion: [What is the deepest place on Mars? Do humans need pressurized suits there?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29949/12102) I got 20 km below the surface for the Armstrong limit and 38 km below for 20 kPa.

Comment: If you're going to talk about going *kilometers* below the surface, where geophysical phenomena are relevant, you have to wonder whether the relevant pressure is the pressure of a hypothetical gas column open to the atmosphere or the pressure due to the rock overburden. The rock pressure rises very rapidly with depth: the one-atmosphere depth is tens of meters for an overburden of rock or regolith.

Comment: @uhoh Why don't you just google yourself? It's not like I'm forcing anyone to believe me. Answers like this are googleable, and if I just pointed to sources, I wouldn't have to write an answer in the first place. If you think I was lying, that's your problem. I was a bit astonished by the temperature of Neptune, since I thought Neptune is warmer than Uranus (despite being farther), but whatever. The Mars link doesn't show how you get to "Armstrong limit 20 km below the surface" but it seems a "what if"-assumption to me. Another answer provides what I hinted above.

Comment: @Giovanni welcome to Stack Exchange! This site works a little differently than other Q&A sites. I'll just repeat the reason(s) I've already mentioned above: "t's generally expected to support answers with sources. While these sound like reasonable numbers, it's impossible for future readers to tell if these are correct or just made-up random numbers." Without supporting sources answer has much less value, thus the change to a down vote Presumably you did have sources for these, so it mentioning them in your Stack Exchange answer should be easier & better than "take my word for it or google it"

Comment: @uhoh Are you awaiting I'll add all the sources into the answer? If you must google it, there is no need for me to answer it anyway. The question isn't "Tell me sources that state the planets' temperatures at 1 bar". And if you take into account I've made up random numbers, that's up to you. I've rounded the Venus number (30 deg C) but that's about correct for 1 bar level. And I don't have to cite the Earth value at all, obviously. Of course it's also rounded a bit.

Comment: @uhoh P.S. thank you for editing my answer, it looks better now.